# Am I using useEffect and unsubscribing properly?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, unsubscribe

I'm trying to learn useState and useEffect which I'm starting to get but came unstuck when React said I had a memory leak. To be honest, I hadn't even realised I was creating memory leaks before and I'm still not entirely sure what causes them, in spite of reviewing the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

If anyone wouldn't mind reviewing what I've written below for a very simple Navbar, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../context/auth';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import { Button, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

function NavBar(props) {
  const { setAuthTokens } = useAuth();
  const { authTokens } = useAuth();
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authTokens) setLoggedIn(true);

    return function cleanup() {
      setLoggedIn();
    };
  }, [isLoggedIn, authTokens]);

  function logOut() {
    setAuthTokens();
  }

  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href='/'>The System</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href='/dashboard'>Dashboard</Nav.Link>
            <Button onClick={logOut}>Log out</Button>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href='/'>The System</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Login />
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: You are setting state (setLoggedIn) into the cleanup function. By the time, this clean up function is called and your setLoggedIn function is called, component already has been removed(unmounted) and that's why react is giving memory leak error.

Comment: The thing is, I don't get a memory leak error when I include it in the cleanup function. With the code exactly as I pasted it, everything works. I just don't understand why it works and that's what worries me.

Answer (score 0):

The return function in useEffect is equivalent to componentWillUnmount. So in case of unmounting you should call logout method (If you are not persisting the session).

Comment: Thanks, that helps make a little more sense.